# How to get collection of IDs, and Selected Dropdown values passed from View's table to Controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I have a checklist/task manager kind of application that basically pulls a bunch of string values from a database using a model, and then pipes it out to a view which uses a expand/collapse patterned table. The only element that an end user modifiers beyond the expand/collapse state is the dopdown list for the project status.

Rather than an update button for each row, the customer wants basically a single button on the bottom of the page which updates all the rows the user changed. So my goal is to try and create said button. As far as the View code snippet, I've tried messing around with Html.BeginForm, but haven't been able to figure out how to also capture the multiple item IDs as well:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateDB", "Checklist", new { id = model.ID })) // model does not exist in this current context
{
<table id="checklistGrid" class="table table-bordered table-striped grid">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ww)</th>
        .... // more table headers
    </tr>
    @foreach (var group in Model.GroupBy(x => x.ww))
        {
        <tr class="group-header">
            <td colspan="12">
                <span class="h2">@group.Key</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        foreach (var dept in group.GroupBy(x => x.dept))
        {
            <tr class="dept-header">
                <td colspan="12">
                    <span class="h4">@dept.Key</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            foreach (var item in dept)
            {
                <tr class="row-header">
                    <td> @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ID)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ww)</td>
                    .... // more table columns

                    <td>
                        @{
                            List<string> ddl = new List<string> { "Done", "Not Done", "N/A" };
                            SelectList sl = new SelectList(ddl, item.status);
                            @Html.DropDownList("newStatus", sl); // Added
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.applied_by)</td>
                    <td>
                        @{
                            DateTime tmp;

                            //Check if not null, if not null convert to specified time zone
                            if (DateTime.TryParse(item.timestamp.ToString(), out tmp))
                            {
                                tmp = item.timestamp ?? DateTime.MinValue;

                                string zoneName = "India Standard Time";
                                var abbrZoneName = TimeZoneNames.TimeZoneNames.GetAbbreviationsForTimeZone(zoneName, "en-US");
                                TimeZoneInfo zoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zoneName);
                                DateTime istTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(tmp, zoneInfo);

                                @Html.Raw(istTime.ToString() + " (" + abbrZoneName.Generic + ")");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.timestamp);
                            }
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    }
</table>
<p><input type="submit" value="Save Changes" /></p>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Hide/Show Dept's Data on Click
    $(function () {
        $('.dept-header').click(function () {
            $(this).nextUntil('.dept-header, .group-header').toggle();
        });
    });

    $(function () {
        $('.group-header').click(function () {
            var elm = $(this);
            if (elm.next().is(":visible")) {
                elm.nextUntil('.group-header').hide();
            } else {
                elm.nextUntil('.group-header', '.dept-header').show();
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

I suspect the easier (and computationally quicker way) would to be to use Jquery + Ajax && Json attached to a button onclick at the bottom to send the collection of id and selected dropdown text to an `ActionResult` in the `Controller` (to then update the database) and then refresh on the success Ajax callback. However my Jquery/Javascript foo is weak and given the clickable 'header' type rows that expand/collapse the data rows, it's not clear to me how I would efficiently use Jquery to navigate and grab the `item.ID`and the selected dropdown text from each row, bundle it up, and pipe to the desired ActionResult.

So how do I send both the id and selected dropdown text of all the rows to an arbitrary `ActionResult` be it with `Html.BeginForm` or Jquery et al?

EDIT: Model for reference:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TaskTracker.Models
{
    [Table("some_update")]
    public class TaskInfo
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "WW")]
        public int ww { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "File Name")]
        public string filename { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Dept")]
        public string hsd_unit { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Owner")]
        public string owner { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Manager")]
        public string manager { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Project")]
        public string project { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Status")]
        public string status { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Applied By")]
        public string applied_by { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Updated Time Stamp")]
        public DateTime? timestamp { get; set; }
    }

    public class TaskInfoDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<TaskInfo> TaskInfoSet { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need javascript, and unless you want to stay on the same page then ajax is not appropriate either. You can simply post the form and bind to your model, but your current view wont work because your using a `foreach` loop and as a result generating duplicate `name` attributes which have no relationship at all to your model and duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html. Your need to use `for` loops or an `EditorTemplate`. You need to show your model in order to correct this.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response; model posted @StephenMuecke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems with you view including your form controls have duplicate `name` attributes meaning you cannot bind to you model when you submit, duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html, and your creating a dropdownist with a name that is not even a property of your model. In addition your use of queries in the view code is not good practice. All of this can be solved by using view models and generating your html correctly using `for` loops (not `foreach` loops) or a custom `EditorTemplate`. However, since you have indicated a preference for ajax, you can post the data by making the following changes to the view

Replace the following HtmlHelper methods

```
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ID)
@Html.DropDownList("newStatus", sl)
```

with

```
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ID, new { id = "", @class = "id" })
@Html.DropDownList("Status", sl, new { id = "", @class = "status" })
```

This will remove the invalid `id` attributes and add class names for selection. Then replace the submit button with

```
<button type="button" id="save">Save Changes</button>
```

And add the following script

```
var rows = $('.row-header'); // store all the table rows containing the form controls
$('#save').click(function() {
  // Build an array of the values to post back
  var data = [];
  $.each(rows, function() {
    data.push({id: $(this).find('.id').val(), status: $(this).find('.status').val() });
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateDB", "Checklist")',
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ model: data },
    traditional: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
      // do something?
    }
  })
});
```

Then create a model to accept the values

```
public class TaskInfoUpdate
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

And modify you POST method to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateDB(IEnumerable<TaskInfoUpdate> model)
```

Side note: Its not clear what you mean by *"and then refresh on the success Ajax callback"* (what is there to refresh?). I suggest that the method return either `return Json(true);` if the items were successfully saved, or `return Json(null);` (or a `HttpStatusCodeResult`) if not so that you can notify the user as appropriate.

Comment: My preference is for the best method, based on perusing similar questions people tended to comment that ajax was better because it was faster, etc so that's why I bothered to mention it instead of requesting something that used solely `Html.BeginForm`. However, this works nicely enough and when I later have the time to go back I'll probably see if I can get it to work by switching `foreach` to `for` and add a `ViewModel` w/ a `DropDown` type to allow binding (I originally thought it was too much hassle to convert from the DB model to a VM for each item, but it might be cleanest OOD after all)

Comment: The 'best' method depends on what you want to do when you submit. If you want to stay on the same page and continue making changes, then use ajax. If you want to save and redirect to another page then don't use ajax. Note I have rolled back your edit. Using `location.reload()` makes no sense at all (it would be reloading exactly the save view you currently have, making the use of ajax pointless and degrading performance)